# Automation of sql reports from raw database guide needed

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, cron, automation

I have a database which is taking some statistical raw data continuously from a website and being saved in my database. How can I apply SQL queries on that data and keep publishing reports of them similar to the stock exchange live feed or others

I can export my database results in excel format from phpmyadmin and just copy paste the excel in MS access everytime i get new information and get the queries but this is manual. I want the whole processes to be automated like getting data in the database, applying sql queries and generating graphs/reports everytime new data comes. Something like cronjon will work? or other methods?

Please guide

Thanks

Comment: This statistical raw data... how do you accumulate to your database continuously? How does Excel fit in?  Where and how is your intended output generated?

Comment: I am using webscrapping which is actually extracting information from a website and saving it in my database. If i export it I can save it as excel

Comment: Design is an issue-- as the day goes on, the saved data grows larger, and the queries grow longer.  If this is an issue, perhaps interim results need to be saved, and combined with later arriving data to create a fresher interim, and reporting then uses the latest interim... nu